# Information on various patterns for log in/join and in which context to use them?

Tags: design-patterns, login, content

Does anyone have any information regarding log in and register interactions, specifically which patterns to use in which contexts?

For example: A site where you can view most of the content without logging in, but want to build a community. One solution would be: use a typical login | Register area in the header and then use the content to drive links to "Join now"

Answer (score 3):

Lazy registration is a way to allow users to try the site out before they sign up.
Kayak is one of the cleanest lazy registration systems around. When you search for vacation, car or flight prices, it saves your data and always keeps your recent searches on the right-side of the page, until you login or register.

Both these links will fetch cleaner solutions -

http://webjackalope.com/lazy-registration/

http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/LazyRegistration

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can edit your previous response and add the links with the explanation to it.